# Access: SQL SELECT Columns FROM Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to create two CombiFields in an Access Form:

- the first one should show all Table Names of the DB in a dropdown(*)
- and the second one should show all column names from the Table which has been choosed in the first Combifield.

Any ideas?

(*) I already have the first Code:

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.Flags)=0) AND ((MSysObjects.Type)=1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try bellow code in AfterUpdate of first combo

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()
Dim TableName As String
TableName = Me.Combo0.Value
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentProject.Connection.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, Array(Empty, Empty, TableName))
Dim fldname As String
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
fldname = fldname & rs!Column_Name & ";"
rs.MoveNext
Loop
Me.Combo2.RowSource = fldname
Me.Combo2.RowSourceType = "Value List"
Me.Combo2.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still cant get it running...To sum up: The first Combobox (Combo1) shows the TableNames so far. I add the AfterUpdate Code from nazark to that. And I add AfterUpdate Code from Gustav to the second Combobox (Combo2). Now I get a Compile Error for the Code "Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset" Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You cannot mix and toss everything just like that. You need only and nothing more than my single line of code (above). The second combobox needs zero code.

Comment: you need to add Reference to microsoft activex Data Object library 2.6 from the tool menu of code windows

Comment: the code above is to get column name in the second combo

Answer (score 3):

Set the *RowSource* property of the combobox to the name of the table (=ComboBoxTable).

Then set the *RowSourceType* property to: Field List

```
Private Sub ComboBoxTable_AfterUpdate()

    Me!ComboBoxFields.RowSource = Me!ComboBoxTable.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually i dont really get it. Should i write "=ComboBoxTable" in the RowSource? Or is there also any SQL Code which works?

Comment: No, use the _AfterUpdate_ event of the table combobox. See edit.